# Problem with deleting in Node.js, Mongodb, Ajax, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I'm having trouble getting my delete button to work. I have a table with 4 row also a delete button. I have written this code and would like to delete a task, through fileName or _id.

Code in Server.js

```
app.delete("/deleteTask/:id", function (req, res) {
console.log("TEST");
const task_id = req.params.id;
taskCollection.deleteOne({ "_id" : ObjectId(task_id) }, function (err, success) {
    console.log(success);
    res.redirect("/");
});
res.send(); });
```

Code in View.js

```html
$.ajax({
    "url": "/featured-tasks",
    "method": "GET"
}).done(function(tasks) {
    tasks.forEach(function(task) {
        const taskCard =   "<tr class='task-card'>" +
                                 "<td class='title'>" + task.title +  "</td>" + "<td class='description'>" + task.description + "</td>" +
                                 "<td class='courses'>" + task.courses + "</td>" + 
                                 "<td class='task'>" + "<a href='/view?task=" + task.fileName + "'>" + task.fileName +"</a>" + "</td>" +
                                 "<td>" + "<button id='taskdelete' class='btn-delete' data-target='/deleteTask/' data-method='DELETE' data-disabled='true'>" + "Delete" +"</button>" + "</td>" +
                                 "</tr>";
        $(".task-gallery").append(taskCard);
    })
});


$('#taskdelete').on('click', function() {
    const taskFileName = $(this).attr('task.fileName');
    console.log("test");
    $.ajax({
       method: "DELETE",
       url: "/deleteTask/" + taskFileName,
       success: function(result) { {
              location.reload();
          }
       }
    })
 });
```

HTML fragment for table:

```html
<table class="task-gallery">
<tbody>
<tr class="tableHeader">
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Courses</th>
<th>PDF-file</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<script src="home/home.js"></script>
<tr class="task-card">
<td class="title">Larman</td>
<td class="description">lektier</td>
<td class="courses">info</td>
<td class="task"><a href="/view?task=file.pdf">file.pdf</a></td>
<td><button class="btn-delete" data-filename="file.pdf" data-method="DELETE" data-disabled="true">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You sure this is correct? `const taskFileName = $(this).attr('task.fileName');` Your taskdelete button doesn't seem to have any attribute called 'task.fileName'.

Comment: I'm not sure it's right. But do not quite know what I've done wrong or why it does not work.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(taskFileName)` just under `const taskFileName`? It should return the id of the task document you want to delete.

Comment: There is nothing coming out of the terminal, nor my console.log ("test"), Do not know what went wrong, it used to be

Comment: It should show on when you click on delete button.

Comment: Yes but nothing happens when I click on delete button. Do not know why nothing works

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to change in your frontend code:

- Id values for HTML elements need to be unique so you can't use your click handler
- You need to set the `task.fileName` value as an attribute of the delete button.
- The `onclick` event handler should be on the container element.

Here is some updated code for you to try:

```
$.ajax({
  "url": "/featured-tasks",
  "method": "GET"
}).done(function(tasks) {
  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
      const taskCard = "<tr class='task-card'>" +
        "<td class='title'>" + task.title +  "</td>" + "<td class='description'>" + task.description + "</td>" +
        "<td class='courses'>" + task.courses + "</td>" + 
        "<td class='task'>" + "<a href='/view?task=" + task.fileName + "'>" + task.fileName +"</a>" + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + "<button class='btn-delete' data-filename='" + task.fileName + "' data-method='DELETE' data-disabled='true'>" + "Delete" +"</button>" + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
      $(".task-gallery").append(taskCard);
    })
});


$('.task-gallery .btn-delete').on('click', function() {
  const taskFileName = $(this).attr('data-filename');
  console.log("test");
  $.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: "/deleteTask/" + taskFileName,
    success: function(result) {
      location.reload();
    }
  })
});
```

On the server side you should check for an error:

```
app.delete("/deleteTask/:id", function (req, res) {
  console.log("TEST");
  const task_id = req.params.id;
  taskCollection.deleteOne({ _id : ObjectId(task_id) }, function (err, success) {
    if (err){
      console.log("failed");
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(success);
    res.redirect("/");
  });
  res.send();
});
```

The code I have provided is correct, run the code snippet to verify it for yourself:

```js
var tasks = [
  {
    title: "A Course",
    description: "Description of A",
    courses: "Course A",
    fileName: "file-A.pdf"
  },
  {
    title: "B Course",
    description: "Description of B",
    courses: "Course B",
    fileName: "file-B.pdf"
  },
  {
    title: "C Course",
    description: "Description of C",
    courses: "Course C",
    fileName: "file-C.pdf"
  }
];

tasks.forEach(function(task) {
  const taskCard = "<tr class='task-card'>" +
  "<td class='title'>" + task.title +  "</td>" + "<td class='description'>" + task.description + "</td>" +
  "<td class='courses'>" + task.courses + "</td>" + 
  "<td class='task'>" + "<a href='/view?task=" + task.fileName + "'>" + task.fileName +"</a>" + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + "<button class='btn-delete' data-filename='" + task.fileName + "' data-method='DELETE' data-disabled='true'>" + "Delete" +"</button>" + "</td>" +
  "</tr>";
  $(".task-gallery").append(taskCard);
});

$('.task-gallery .btn-delete').on('click', function() {
  const taskFileName = $(this).attr('data-filename');
  // spit out the 'data-filename' value
  window.alert('Delete ' + taskFileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="task-gallery">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableHeader">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Courses</th>
      <th>PDF-file</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. Have just tried the code. But there is something that does not work because I do not get any console.log () out when I click the button.

Comment: No nothing at all.

Comment: Run this code in the console window and see how many matching elements there are: `document.querySelectorAll('.task-gallery .btn-delete')`

Comment: Nothing appears again, just think I'm trying to start it all over again

Comment: Starting over seems an extreme measure - you should work through the problem so that you learn how to debug the code. If the `document.querySelectorAll()` call isn't returning any results then the selector is the issue. What web browser are you using?

Comment: My website shows and features work, but nothing happens when I click on the button in the console on the browser or in MS Visual Studio. I'm using google chrome

Comment: In Google Chrome right click on the element containing a delete button and select `Inspect`, this will open the Developer Tools. Right click on the HTML code for the button element and click `Copy > Copy selector` and paste the result here.

Comment: body > div.content > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(5) > button

Comment: <td><button class="btn-delete" data-filename="Application layer.pdf" data-method="DELETE" data-disabled="true">Delete</button></td>

Comment: What element has the `task-gallery` class attribute? Run `document.querySelectorAll('.task-gallery')` in the console.

Comment: <table class="task-gallery">

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the HTML fragment for the table?

Comment: I want you to add the HTML code for the table to the question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: <table class="task-gallery">
        <tbody><tr class="tableHeader">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Courses</th>
            <th>PDF-file</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    <script src="home/home.js"></script>
<tr class="task-card"><td class="title">Larman</td><td class="description">lektier</td><td class="courses">info</td><td class="task"><a href="/view?task=file.pdf">file.pdf</a></td><td><button class="btn-delete" data-filename="file.pdf" data-method="DELETE" data-disabled="true">Delete</button></td></tr>

Comment: What is the purpose of the `home/home.js` script and why is it buried in the table?

Comment: That was a mistake home/home.js came with is it not in the table

Comment: thanks for the help :) i try something else, instead of this way I've made it :)

Comment: I've added a code snippet to demonstrate the skeleton of the code works.